# How to read files on an API route correctly with Vercel deployment

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nitro

I have an API route where I need to read all files from a directory and also do some computation with it.
The files should not be public and are currently located inside the project root under `/characters`.

`server/api/read-characters`

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from "path";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const folder = path.join(process.cwd(), 'characters')
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folder)
    return files;
})
```

This works fine when developing locally, but when deployed to Vercel, the serverless function has no access to the files and throws an error.

I know about Nitro server assets, but I think I can only address specific files using `useStorage` , not a whole folder directly?

How do I do this correctly?

**Sidenote:** the files are images that I overlay to create a new image.
I have a quite large set of possible images `> 50mb`, which need to be available (but not all are used every time). The computation should be as fast as possible, because the functionality is used very often.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I'm using an external storage solution to store the images and then fetch the files in the serverless function. Since the files are imported using a filepath, using nitro useStorage was not a viable solution for me. The file-structure is generated at build time by using a nuxt pre-generated api route, because you can read the files using node:fs here.